# Sending a serialized Protobuf message over SSH

Tags: python, ssh, protocol-buffers

so I am trying to send over serialized protobuf messages over SSH and deserialize them on my local machine. However, for some reason when I send over the serialized string, I get a DecodeError saying that I am trying to deserialize a Truncated Message.

The way I have this setup is I have two scripts, one being run on the server through Popen and ssh on my local script. The script being run on the server is simply printing the message.SerializeToString() to stdout and then I am collecting that output through Popen.stdout on my local script. Here are some code snippets:

Local Machine Script:

```
magic_str = 'this_is_magical'
ssh = subprocess.Popen('ssh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx logsearch.py', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in ssh.stdout:
  #this is just the specific protobuf message structure I created
  l = log_pb2.LogLine()

  #restore the internal newlines, discussed below
  l.ParseFromString(line.replace(magic_str, '\n'))
```

Server Script (logsearch.py):

```
  #get some LogLine object named l, and we replace the internal newlines with
  #magic_str because it messes up reading line by line in the local script
  magic_str = 'this_is_magical'
  print l.SerializeToString().replace('\n', magic_str)
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide me with, it is much appreciated. If any extra information is needed or if anything is unclear, please let me know and I will make sure to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do is to forget about actually trying to deserialize, and just check: did you get back the right binary, after running your magic replacements. Check it is **exactly** the same binary (not text) as the original.

If you are fundamentally taking text, it might be wiser to simply base-64 encode the data prior to transmission, and base-64 decode it on the other side. Then you won't need to worry about any replacements.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. It turns out the binary string was not exactly the same after sending it over SSH, so doing a simple base64 encode before I sent the data over resolved my issues. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're doing here entirely, but are you sure you want to be creating a new LogLine-message for each *line* in the ssh.stdout? Protobuf deserialization requires the entire message to be able to deserialize properly. Something like

```
ssh_data = #... parse all the data received from the pipe (not line for line)
l = log_pb2.LogLine()
l.ParseFromString(ssh_data.replace(magic_str, '\n'))
```